# Getting the button press on recycler view item which is created with method

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview, onclick

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and Java overall so this might be simple question but I couldn't find any solutions or either couldn't use them to fix my issue.

So I have a RecyclerView which I can insert items from a list of pre-defined items with the function "addItems()" when I press to a button and display them.

Also those items have ImageButtons -which is just a transparent rectangle- to get individual clicks on them.

The purpose of these ImageButtons are to switch to a new activity which I defined in the "addItems()" method.

But the problem is, I can't catch -but they respond to the clicks- click on those items, and also I can't pass the activity class or the layout file.

To be exact, I want to use these buttons to switch to a new activity and display the info of that item there.

It's my first question here, so if I need to show any code, please tell me to.

NewsAdapter.java

```
package com.example.yiyecek2.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.yiyecek2.R;

import java.util.List;

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder>
{
    Context mContext;
    List<NewsItem> mData;


    public NewsAdapter(Context mContext, List<NewsItem> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View layout;
        layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.lyt_restoran,viewGroup,false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(layout);
    }
    // Changed below ----------
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder, int position) {
        // Bind data here
        newsViewHolder.tvSellerName.setText(mData.get(position).getSellerName());
        newsViewHolder.tvSellerAddress.setText(mData.get(position).getSellerAddress());
        newsViewHolder.ivSellerImage.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getSellerImage());
        newsViewHolder.tvMinCost.setText(mData.get(position).getMinCost());
        newsViewHolder.tvMinTime.setText(mData.get(position).getMinTime());
        newsViewHolder.tvDeliveryCost.setText(mData.get(position).getDeliveryCost());
        newsViewHolder.tvClassToGo.setText(mData.get(position).getClassToGo());
        // Line below is the buttons attached to the items which I aim to use on switching Activities
        newsViewHolder.ibGoSellerPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SiparisActivity.this, classDominos.class);
                startActivity(intent); // startActivity is marked red
            }
        });
    }
    // Changed above ----------
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvSellerName, tvSellerAddress, tvMinCost, tvMinTime, tvDeliveryCost, tvClassToGo;
        ImageView ivSellerImage;
        ImageButton ibGoSellerPage;

        public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSellerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFoodName);
            tvSellerAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFoodDescription);
            ivSellerImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFoodImage);
            tvMinCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFoodCost);
            tvMinTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMinTime);
            tvDeliveryCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryCost);
            tvClassToGo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClassToGo);
            ibGoSellerPage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibGoSellerPage);
            //int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Position is: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

SiparisActivity.java //this is where I list restaurant items with ImageButtons said above.

```
package com.example.yiyecek2.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.yiyecek2.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import recyclerview.CustomItemAnimator;

public class SiparisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnListRestaurants;
    RecyclerView NewsRecyclerView;
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
    List<NewsItem> mData;
    ImageButton ibGoSellerPage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_siparis);

        // Hide the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        NewsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.news_rv);
        btnListRestaurants = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonListRestaurants);

        NewsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        NewsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        NewsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new CustomItemAnimator());


        // Get clicks on the "List Restaurants"
        btnListRestaurants.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int restaurantCount = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Listing Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                Timer timerToTransition;
                timerToTransition = new Timer();
                TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        addItems();
                        restaurantCount++;
                        if (restaurantCount > 9)
                        {
                            System.out.println(restaurantCount);
                            timerToTransition.cancel(); // Stops the timer when theres 10 Restaurants listed
                        }
                    }
                };
                timerToTransition.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,300); // waits 300ms before creating a new Restaurant
            }
        });

        if (ibGoSellerPage != null) // Check if Restaurant button exists
        {
            System.out.println("ON CLICK HERE");
            ibGoSellerPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    System.out.println("ON CLICK HERE");
                }
            });
        }

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        // fill list news with pre defined data

        // Adapter ini and setup
        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this,mData);
        NewsRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        NewsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void addItems()
    {
        RecyclerView.State state = null;
        int switchInt = 0; // To use in the switch
        // Random integer list to assign switchInt a random value

        int[] intList;
        intList = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        // Pick a random int
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(5);

        // Check if the array's index isn't empty(-1)
        while (intList[rndInt] != -1)
        {
            switchInt = (int) intList[rndInt];
            intList[rndInt] = -1;
        }
        //System.out.println(rndInt);
        switch(switchInt) {
            case 0:
                mData.add(0,new NewsItem("Domino's Pizza","Sarıgöl, Ordu Cd. No:128, 34240 Gaziosmanpaşa/İstanbul",
                        R.drawable.dominos,"32 TL","30 dk.","0 TL","classDominos")); // I'm trying to catch that "classDominos" to use to switch Activity
                break;
            case 1:
                mData.add(0,new NewsItem("Migros","Bağlarbaşı, Küçükköy Yolu Cd., 34245 Gaziosmanpaşa/İstanbul",
                        R.drawable.migroslogo,"32 TL","25 dk.","0 TL", "classDominos"));
                break;
            case 2:
                mData.add(0,new NewsItem("KFC","Yeşilpınar Mah. Şehit Metinkaya Sok Vialand AVM No:11 Mağaza No:237, 34065 Eyüpsultan",
                        R.drawable.kfclogo,"32 TL","35 dk.","3 TL", "classDominos"));
                break;
            case 3:
                mData.add(0,new NewsItem("Popeyes","Yeşilpınar Mah. Şehit Metin Kaya Sok. No:11 K:3 Vialand AVM, 34065",
                        R.drawable.popeyeslogo,"32 TL","35 dk.","3 TL", "classDominos"));
                break;
            case 4:
                mData.add(0,new NewsItem("Mado","İslambey, Hz. Halid Blv. No:43 D:B, 34050 Eyüpsultan/İstanbul",
                        R.drawable.madologo,"32 TL","35 dk.","3 TL", "classDominos"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Added item");
        newsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
        NewsRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(NewsRecyclerView, state, 0);
        
        // Un-commenting the lines below crash the app when "Listing Restaurants" (Creating items)
        //ibGoSellerPage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibGoSellerPage);
        /*ibGoSellerPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("ON CLICK HERE");
            }
        });
        */
    }
}
```

I can see the individual buttons in the profiler but how to catch clicks on them? (You can see I'm holding the button on the right)
[Profiler Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLfWs.png)

Comment: do you have some sort of onClickListener for the imageButtons? Show your recyclver view adapter and the activity hosting the recyclver view.

Comment: @BabyishTank I've edited the main post with those. I tried my best to put an onClickListener but I get crashes if I put it on the onCreate event of the activity as the button doesn't exists before user presses a button to list items. So I couldn't find a way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with you is that the click event happen on the screen in another view

By making a transparent rectangle i think the click go to the parent view
Try to test that for ex:

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/layout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
        
 <ImageButton
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        
</LinearLayout>
```

handle the click on `layout` view if it work so you need to change the transparent rectangle button to a bold one or another approach

better to add some code from your side to help us understand the problem well

Comment: the problem is I don't know where I should put the onClickListener. If I put it on the Activity onCreate, the button doesn't exist so it throws a crash. I did a if != null check but still can't catch clicks. So it probably doesn't happen on another view.

Comment: Sure it will throws a null crash cause the button belong to the list item so you must but the click listener inside the adapter you make

Comment: first define the imageButton in the viewHolder as you made with the TextView then access the imageButton inside the onBindViewHolder

Comment: Updated the main post with changes. I defined the ImageButton as you said and tried to put onClickListener to onBindViewHolder but startActivity is marked red, its undefined here I assume.

Comment: startActivity need the Activity context to be called, and here you pass the context to the adapter so you can use your code will be like this

Intent intent = new Intent(SiparisActivity.this, classDominos.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);